# How to add to array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'm sure this is simple but I can't seem to get it:

Works:

```
@build1 = Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314)
@build2 = Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,4,18317)
@build = @build1 + @build2
```

What I want to work...

```
#for item in @cart.items do
#  @build << Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314)
#end
```

Doesn't work either...

```
#(1..3).each do |i|
#  @build << Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314)
#end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the two iterating examples you'd need to set `@build` prior to calling `<<` on it.

I'm not sure what `build_booking` is returning but if it's an array (I'm guessing from the first, working, example) then you'd probably want to add the result of `build_booking` to `@build`. E.g.

```
@build = []
for item in @cart.items do
  @build += Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314)
end
```

Comment: ah perfect... i tried += as my first guess but forgot the Array.new!

Comment: This is probably a good place to use inject too. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003171

Comment: I think the approach of Magnar is better than most here, since it generates the array by converting cart items into bookings directly instead of explicitly declaring an array and then making incremental alterations using the += operator.

Array#map or the alternative name Array#collect is a very powerful tool.

Comment: @dylanfm #inject would certainly work, but it's overkill; #map works just fine!

Answer (score 27):

I prefer using the wonderful array-methods that ruby has to offer over a for loop:

```
@build = @cart.items.map { |item| Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314) }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@build` will need to be an array, or an object that responds to `<<`, for `@build <<` to work.

When you've done:

```
@build = @build1 + @build2
```

What is the value of `@build`?

Comment: according to the console after the addition @build.class = Array as are @build1 and @build2

Answer (score 0):

```
@build = []
for item in @cart.items do
  @build += Booking.build_booking('2009-06-13',3,2,18314)
end


 @build.flatten!
```

**flatten  will will work even Booking.build_booking is returning an array of bookings**

Answer (score 0):

The quick approach, though, would be to simply declare the array to combine the two elements:

```
@build = [ @build1, @build2 ]
```

I'd use an approach like Magnar, though, which is much more concise.